# "She might have been living there for 8 years" = "Perhaps she has been living there for 8 years"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, might

- "She **might** have been living there for 8 years"
- "**Perhaps** she has been living there for 8 years"

Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither of them is formally correct for the meaning that's almost certainly intended (speaker doesn't know exactly how long she has/has been living there, but 8 years sounds about right). In fact, both your versions (which mean exactly the same) simply present the possibility that she lived there for 8 years OR SHE DIDN'T (perhaps she never even lived there at all, the alternative is unspecified).

Comment: An "accurate" version with the normal meaning is *"She has been living there for **perhaps** 8 years"*.

Comment: She might [It is possible that she has] have been living there for x years. When you are not sure.

Comment: @Lambie, I didn't quite understand your comment. Do you mean the first sentence is wrong?

Comment: What's the context? Normally you'd use "she might have lived there" or "perhaps she lived there" in preference to the perfect forms. If you were talking about something that happened 8 years into a longer stay, you could use "She might have been living there for 8 years when her nephew moved in". Although in most contexts you'd probably use "I think" or some other way of expressing uncertainty. In appraising the precise meaning you need to consider the degree of certainty, whether it's opinion or fact being stated, and what is being contradicted or what is improbable or unlikely in contrast.

Comment: No, yunus, I am saying that might there is the same as It is possible that. Neither sentence is wrong. She might have been living there for 8 years [when her dog ran away.]

Comment: She moved in yesterday, but the way she acted, she might have been living there for eight years. That sense can't be carried by the second example.

Comment: @Lambie, Ahhh I get it now. This is new for me. So, "she might have been living there for 8 years when her dog ran away" is clearly a past situation. But, then why don't we say "She might have lived there for 8 years when her dog ran away"? to emphasize the past, because I always thought "....might have been living ...." refers to the present because it has "....have been living..." as in the case of "..present perfect continues ..." which refers to the present.

Comment: You can use either the present perfect or PPC. "might have been living" is past also. One emphasizes the "activity" (living for a time) and the other is just past (lived). But "have been + verbING" is always past, yunus.